# Oracle standby database recovery stopped

Tags: oracle, recovery, standby

I have a primary and an standby database.
Because my file-system became full in standby database, the recovery has stopped in standby.

This is the present state of sequences in primary and standby:

```
Thread Last Sequence Received Last Sequence Applied Difference
```

---

```
     1                    560                   394        166
```

How can I start the recovery again?

Answer (score 1):

You then have the option of either starting a managed recovery operation or opening the database for read-only access.

Start the database:

```
SQL> STARTUP NOMOUNT;
```

Mount the standby database:

```
SQL> ALTER DATABASE MOUNT STANDBY DATABASE;
```

Start the managed recovery operation:

```
SQL> ALTER DATABASE RECOVER MANAGED STANDBY DATABASE 
  2> DISCONNECT FROM SESSION;
```

Comment: standby is already in mounted state. should I shut it down and start it u in mounted or I can just stop the recovery and start the recovery again?

Comment: I would shut it down and start it in mounted, then if that doesn't work, start recovery again.

Comment: was this helpful?

Comment: I had to take incremental and copy it there and then recover.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have gaps , meaning deleted arch logs from your primary you simply go to the standby:

startup mount;

then start the recovery process with real time apply:

alter database recover managed standby database using current logfile disconnect;

Read-only means that you can issue select queries on the standby, this however requires licensing.

Comment: If stby is mounted you can stop the recovery process:                             alter database recover managed standby database cancel;                             and start it with the other alter command afterwards OR stop it , startit up in mount and start the recovery, it does not matter as the MRP will pick up from where it needs